# Is $n^2>n^2/m + nm$ for $m$ taking some value between $1$ and $n$.

Tags: number-theory

This is not a homework question. I am working on this paper and I need to come up with a proof for this, I will not include this is in the paper but I need to be sure of this or I will end up looking like idiot :(

$1 < m < n$, m is a integer

Comment: I assume you mean exclusive? Otherwise it fails for any $n$ with $m=1$

Comment: Presumably, $m$ is strictly between $1$ and $n$ and $m$ is an integer?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I forgot to mention that its 1 and N exclusive

Comment: Still need to know if it is $m$ an integer. (It's definitely not true if $m$ is allowed to be a non-integer.)

Comment: Take $n=4$ and $m=3$ then we have $16 > 16/3 + 12$, which is not true since $16/3 > 4$.

Answer (score 2):

This inequality is not true. Take $n=4$ and $m=3$ then the inequality gives $16 > 16/3 + 12$, which is not true since $16/3 > 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by $n^2$ on both sides, this reduces to $1>\frac{1}{m}+\frac{m}{n}$. Letting $m=n-1$, then $\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{n-1}{n}>\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}=1$. So for any $n$, this is false, except $n=2$.

Comment: Hey if I write this result in my paper, will I run into any problem ? is it fine if I use the equation sir ?